# Recorrer dos filas de un excel con una condición con openpyxl y Python

Tags: python, openpyxl

Buen día,

Estoy realizando un pequeño programa en python para leer varios ficheros en excel (son cuadrantes de horas que realizando los trabajadores, dividido por pestañas que son los meses del año).

Por otro lado tengo un vector con los trabajadores que debe buscar en cada fichero, las horas realizadas del mes.

Esta parte ya la tengo funcionando y va correctamente, sólo tengo una parte del código que no está del todo optimizado. La parte que quiero mejorar es el kit de la cuestión por lo que he abierto este hilo.

Les pongo el mini código que estoy preparando:

> ```
> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>
> libros = "test.xlsx"
> trabajadores = "Nombre y apellidos trabajador"
>
> libro_in = load_workbook(libros)
> hoja_in = libro_in['Enero']
>
> Calculo las dimensiones del excel
> dimension_excel = hoja_in.dimensions
> mi_fila = hoja_in.min_row
> ma_fila = hoja_in.max_row
> mi_columna = hoja_in.min_column
> ma_columna = hoja_in.max_column
>
> for row in hoja_in.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_col=1, max_row=ma_fila):
>     for cell in row:
>         # Busco al trabajador en el excel, siempre aparece en dos filas.
>         if cell.value == trabajadores:
>                 cells=cell.internal_value
>                 print (cell, cells)
>                 Obtengo la celda donde aparece el trabajador.
>
>                 Aquí recorro las columnas del trabajador para recoger los datos de las horas realizadas
>
>                 **for objeto_columna in range (3,ma_columna-2):
>                     horas_merchand = hoja_in.cell(row=cell,column=objeto_columna).value
>                     print (horas_merchand)**
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<module1>", line 33, in <module>
>   File "C:\Users\tpv09.TPVCAN\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\worksheet\worksheet.py",
> ```
>
> line 237, in cell
> if row < 1 or column < 1:
> **TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Cell' and 'int**

El tema es el siguiente:

El código recorre el excel y me indica en que fila se encuentra el trabajador:

> <Cell 'Enero'.A7> SONIA MARÍA MONTESDEOCA QUINTANA
> <Cell 'Enero'.A53>> SONIA MARÍA MONTESDEOCA QUINTANA

Con dicha información recorrer dichas filas entre las columnas 4 y la última columna menos dos:

Falla al interpreter de python encontrar una valor de cell en vez de un int.

horas_merchand = hoja_in.cell(row=cell,column=objeto_columna).value

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia es bien recibida?
Gracias y saludos

Answer (score 0):

yo probaría a cambiar el bucle `for` por un `while`.
Por ejemplo:

```
i = 2 #Empezamos en 2 por las cabeceras

while i <= hoja_in.max_row:
    #El código que tienes dentro del for
```

Con esto creas un bucle hasta que ya no haya más filas, si quieres limitar el número de columnas puedes añadir `hoja_in.max_column`